# Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibrium Problem

Tags: game-theory

Suppose that there are two incumbent icecream vendors, but that there is a possibility of entry of a third vendor. Specifically, at any location on the beach a third vendor can, after observing the locations of the two incumbents, op en at a cost of $c=0.05$ and will serve all clients who are located closest to him.

Question : Find the Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibria of the game. Does there exist an equilibrium where all three firms enter?

Hint: Draw the unit square in the $(x,y)$ plane, and let each vector represent a subgame where firm 1 has chosen location $x$ and firm 2 location $y$. By symmetry, it suffices to analyze the case where $x \leq y$, since other equilibria are easily derived from the equilibria for this case (why?). Partition the region $0 \leq x \leq y$, according to the best response of the firm*. Compute (and draw) the reduced (given the best response of the third firm) best response correspondence of the incumbents.

* In a knife edge case that $x=y$, a best response does not exist. If $z$ is the location of the third firm, any $z\neq x$ is not optimal, since moving closer to $x$ increases market share but taking the location $z=x$ is also not optimal since the market is then shared with two incumbents, and moving slightly away in the right direction leads to an improvement. To avoid this technical difficulty, you may assume that $|z-x| \geq \epsilon$ for $\epsilon >0$ a small number

---

I don't have a clue about how I should approach this question. I already spent hours thinking about it. Could anyone please help?

Comment: It looks like this is a slightly modified version on $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the Hotelling Location Model. However, there is something missing, i.e. the payoff functions of the players (in particular that of player 3).

Comment: Notice that the unique Nash Equilibrium of the 2-players game is the one in which both players choose the intersection point of the  diagonals of the unit square.

Comment: I guess the price of selling ice-creams is normalized to one?

Comment: @Kolmin I've not been given anything else than this. And I thought the same thing as you did about the Nash equilibrium occuring in the middle of the unit square. However, do you have any idea how I could find the SPNE?

Comment: Intuitively I would go for the following symmetric choices for P1 and P2: $(1/4,1/2)$ and $(3/4,1/2)$ (doesn't really matter who does what). The idea is that in this way they do have the same profit of the 2-players case, but at the same time they make entering not profitable for P3 (it is a form of Strategic entry deterrence)...but now the problem is with $c=0.05$. Even if we normalize, still it looks a pretty low cost for P3. Thus, he should still enter.